# Power Query Assistance: How to return the range of three consecutive fields across a row with highest value out of all fields

Tags: max, powerquery

New to Power Query.  Have pieced together what I've needed until now.

I need to return the sum of the three consecutive cells with highest value out of a range of cells.  See the screenshot I provided as an example.  This wouldn't necessarily include the MAX value of a specific cell in the given range.

I can do this all day long in a spreadsheet with MAX function and overlapping arrays.  I can't seem to figure it out with Power Query although I am pretty certain List.Max will be involved somehow.

Help is appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

**March 23rd Edit:**
I've revised and tried both code suggestions but either the code runs on for a very long period for the first suggestion (I killed it after one hour) or the 2nd suggestion errors out unable to find column 'Material 1' (what I renamed the 'Part Number' field in my screenshot).

I failed to mention that my data table has over 20k rows.  I'm having trouble interpreting the M code suggestions you both provided, but are they looping thru each row one-by-one?  Perhaps this is what is causing the lag.  Maybe I would just be better off using VBA to prep the table in advance of Power Query by entering/filling a formula in a new column finding MAX(B1:N^1+C1:N^2+D1:N^3)?  Seems like it might actually be faster in this case?

My version of both code suggestions:

1st Method:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblSource"]}[Content],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Material 1", type text}, {"Sold Month 1", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 2", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 3", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 4", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 5", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 6", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 7", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 8", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 9", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 10", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 11", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 12", Int64.Type}}),

#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Material 1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Material 1", "Attribute", "Value"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns" ,"Sum",(i)=>
    List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [Material 1]=i[Material 1] and [Index]=i[Index]) [Value])+
    List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [Material 1]=i[Material 1] and [Index]=i[Index]+1) [Value])+
    List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [Material 1]=i[Material 1] and [Index]=i[Index]+2) [Value])
    , type number),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns", {"Material 1"}, {{"Max", each List.Max([Sum]), type number}}),
// Merge the max into the original table
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"Material 1"}, #"Grouped Rows",{"Material 1"},"Table1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Max"}, {"Max2"})
in #"Expanded Table1"`
```

2nd Method:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblSource"]}[Content],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Material 1", type text}, {"Sold Month 1", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 2", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 3", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 4", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 5", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 6", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 7", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 8", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 9", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 10", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 11", Int64.Type}, {"Sold Month 12", Int64.Type}}),
i = {"i"}, k = {"Material 1"},
base = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", k, "Col", "Val"),
f = (n)=>let x = Table.Group(base, k, {"t", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "i", n)})
         in Table.Combine(x[t]),
a = f(0),
b = f(1),
c = f(2),
join = Table.NestedJoin(Table.NestedJoin(a,i&k,b,i&k,"a"),i&k,c,i&k,"b"),
add = Table.AddColumn(join, "sum", each List.Sum({[Val],[a][Val]{0}?,[b][Val]{0}?})),
group = Table.Group(add, k, {"max", each List.Max([sum])}),
final = Table.Join(Source, k, group, k)
```

in final

Answer (score 1):

Sample code below

Main trick is unpivot, then using custom column and index to add the current, next, and next+1 row if they are the same Part Number

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Part Number", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type" , {"Part Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index" ,"Sum",(i)=>
    List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index" , each [Part Number]=i[Part Number] and [Index]=i[Index]) [Value])+
    List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index" , each [Part Number]=i[Part Number] and [Index]=i[Index]+1) [Value])+
    List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index" , each [Part Number]=i[Part Number] and [Index]=i[Index]+2) [Value])
    , type number),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Part Number"}, {{"Max", each List.Max([Sum]), type number}}),

// Merge the max into the original table
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"Part Number"}, #"Grouped Rows",{"Part Number"},"Table1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Max"}, {"Max"})
in #"Expanded Table1"
```

Comment: If you had an index already, remove my #"Added Index" row and change the next few rows to use your prior step name instead of #"Added Index" in all instances.  Or add another index and change the references to refer to #"Added Index2"

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it, but it just kept hanging up.  See my post edit.  I guess I will just have to use VBA to enter an array formula unless you see any obvious errors?  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different way:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    i = {"i"}, k = {"Part Number"},
    base = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, k, "Col", "Val"),
    f = (n)=>let x = Table.Group(base, k, {"t", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "i", n)})
             in Table.Combine(x[t]),
    a = f(0),
    b = f(1),
    c = f(2),
    join = Table.NestedJoin(Table.NestedJoin(a,i&k,b,i&k,"a"),i&k,c,i&k,"b"),
    add = Table.AddColumn(join, "sum", each List.Sum({[Val],[a][Val]{0}?,[b][Val]{0}?})),
    group = Table.Group(add, k, {"max", each List.Max([sum])}),
    final = Table.Join(Source, k, group, k)
in
    final
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it, but it just kept error'ing out.  See my post edit.  I guess I will just have to use VBA to enter an array formula unless you see any obvious errors?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: The code works just fine. In the final step you've referred to Source table. But you haven't yet promoted headers, so there are no 'Material 1' column at this step. Besides, you've changed types - depending on the content of 'Material 1' column you may get the empty table at last step. So, you should just replace the first table in the final step: final = Table.Join(#"Changed Type", k, group, k)